# Pass dynamic value to HOC in react

Tags: reactjs, high-order-component

I write some HOC and I need to pass to this HOC a dynamic object that I create on some life cycle level and I did not get him as a prop.
If I try to pass some static value ( for example initialize myObj from start) it works as expected and I get the correct value.

Let's say this is my component class :

```
 let myObj = {};

  class Test extends React.Component
   {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        .....
        }

         render() {
            myObj = {test:'test'};
            return ( ... )
        }       
    }
   export default withHOC(Test, myObj);
```

And this is my HOC:

```
const withHOC = (Component, test) => {
    class Hoc extends React.Component
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
            const s = test; // ---->test is empty object always !!
            ...
        }

     } 
     return Hoc;
 }
```

My 'Dynamic' object that I create on my 'test' class is always empty on my HOC class.
It's happend also when I try to pass some value from my props directly, in this case the page is stuck(without errors in console).

Does someone have any idea how to resolve that? Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling withHOC? You're trying to pass a class called `test` to it??

Comment: @Dominic I just added this part now ,tnx

Comment: At the point you check `test` in the constructor the object will be empty because render happens after that. What are you trying to do with this HOC? Seems there must be a better way to achieve it.

Comment: @Dominic Tnx , I want to be able to create an object on my render in any lifecycle(let's say on constructor , on compunentdidmount , on render etc.) and then pass him to my HOC, is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

When you compose a component that way, composition only happens at compile time (static composition). This means that withHOC runs only once and is receiving an empty `myObj` argument, as it is using the one defined on declaration.

```
export default withHOC(Test, myObj); //myObj = {}
```

If you want that value to be dynamic, the `withHOC` composition should be runned when that value changes.

You can't send data up from the `WrappedComponent` (Test) to the `HOC` (withHOC), so even if you change `myObj` value in `Test.render`, the HOC would never know.

What you could do, if you really need it, is do the composition on the `Test.render`

```
render(){
    const Hoc = withHOC(this.state.myObj, WrappedComponent);//WrappedComponent can be anything
    return(
        <Hoc/>
    )
}
```

This way, every time the component renders, `Hoc` is composed using as `myObj` a value from the component state, wich is not the preferable way to do it, because this.state.myObj might have the same value as it did at the previous render, and you would be re-composing with the same data as before.

A better way to do it is checking for changes in myObj at `Test.componentDidUpdate`, and if it did change, then compose `Hoc` again.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty object to the `withHOC` function

```
let myObj = {}; // <- your myObj is empty

  class Test extends React.Component
   {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        .....
        }

         render() {
            myObj = {test:'test'}; // <- You're doing this in the render method of your Test component, so until the component is rendered myObj is empty
            return ( ... )
        }       
    }
   export default withHOC(Test, myObj);
```

Comment: Tnx for your answer. This is all the point - I want to pass to my HOC object that I create in some life cycle and I don't know him from start, I mean I want to create this object dynamic and then pass him

Comment: Then lift that object as state to the parent component and pass it as prop.

Comment: As a props I success to get everything in my HOC.The question if there is any way to achieve that in another way in this case

Comment: Nope, your constructor of `HOC` will be invoked way before the render method of `Test` so `myObj` will always be empty

Comment: And what about pass specific prop? also doesn't work. for exmaple: export default withHOC(Test, this.props.somePropValue);      this sounds little bit stupid because anyway I get all props but it's doesn't work also, maybe outside of component 'props' is undefined

Comment: how do you propose you have access to `this.props.somePropValue` when you are doing `export default withHOC(Test, this.props.somePropValue);` at the end of your js file?

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation about what's happening here, by order:

1. `import Comp from '.../Test.js'`
2. the `withHOC` function is triggered, with the params of `Test` (which is defined above the call) and `myObj` (which is defined above the call but is empty)
3. Test component is returned, and nobody used the logic of `myObj = {test:'test'}`

Suggested solution:
Make the HOC get the logic from the props with another hoc:

```
const withProps = newProps => BaseComponent => props => {
  const propsToAdd = typeof newProps === 'function' ? newProps(props) : newProps
  return <BaseComponent {...props} {...propsToAdd} />
}
```

Usage:

```
class Test extends React.Component
   {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        .....
        }

         render() {
            return ( ... )
        }       
    }
export default withProps({test:'test'})(withHOC(Test));
// or: export default withProps(props => {test:'test'})(withHOC(Test));

const withHOC = (Component) => {
    class Hoc extends React.Component
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
            const s = this.props.test;
            ...
        }

     } 
     return Hoc;
 }
```

you can use [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose), a library which has many hocs and utils, and for better readability:

```
import { compose, withProps } from "recompose"

class Test extends React.Component {...}

const enhance = compose(
  withProps({test:'test'}),
  withHOC
)
export default enhance(Test);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't say with confidence this is optimal but I solved a similar problem by having a function within the HOC that updates state that you can then invoke with any data in the wrapped component.

HOC:

```
func = (a, b) => {
  this.setState({
    stateA: a,
    stateB: b
  )}
}

return ({ <WrappedComponent func={this.func} /> })
```

Wrapped Component:

```
this.props.func(anythingA, anythingB);
```

You can then access the data through state in the HOC.

To elaborate:

```
const withHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class withHOC extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        stateA: 1,
        stateB: 2
      }
      *use state however you want in this HOC, including pass it through to another component*

      *the following is just a function*
      *when it's invoked in the wrapped component state will update here in the 
 HOC*
      changeState = (a, b) => {
        this.setState({
          stateA: a,
          stateB: b
        )}
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>this.state.stateA</p>
            <p>this.state.stateB</p>
            <WrappedComponent changeState={this.changeState} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In wrappedComponent, after importing:

```
class aComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
    }

    *you can now invoke the function from the HOC in this wrapped component*
  }
}
```

Comment: tnx for your help , but i don't really understand your example , can you share some detail example or sandbox ?

Comment: I've added some further explanation. Hopefully it's clear now! If not let me know what you're not getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-redux and store your object in redux state. Change the object wherever you need (in your case it's in Test) and access it in component inside your HOC from redux state, it'll be always up to date.