# Pass a parameter into namespace in react i18next

Tags: reactjs, react-native, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am using [react i18next](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc) and I need to pass namespace which I get from the previous screen as a navigation prop. Code for my second screen is as follows.

```
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next"
let params = ""

class SecondScreen extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      const { navigation } = props
      params = navigation.getParam("params", {})
    }
    render() {
      ....
    }
}
export default withTranslation([`namespace1/${params}`])(SecondScreen))
```

I got that it can be done using [useTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook), but I need to continue my work with [withTranslation](https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc) as I am using class components. Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work as you are already wrapping your component during the compilation process and so `withTranslation` is getting passed `namespace/`. The injection of props, well, happens during the run.

On the lines of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58668641/5924738), try writing an outer class that wraps this class `SecondScreen` as an inner class with the `withTranslation` HOC in its `render` method.